# extract url and name attributes from the given string

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, text-extraction

the format of the input string is >>

[https://thisisurl.com] This is Name

how to extract "https://thisisurl.com", and "This is url" attributes from it

where the url attribute is given in brackets [???] and remaining text is the name attribute

I want a function that can do this task for me

Comment: do you want to use API in javascript? or what do you mean by your question?

Comment: @AbdelhamedAbdin the question is simple, given a input string in format [1???] 2???, first value is given in bracket and remaining out of the bracket is second value, parse this string and fetch both values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use escape character `\` for this as follow:

```js
const str = '[https://thisisurl.com] This is Name'

const regex = /\[(.*)\] (.*)/i
const matchResult = str.match(regex)

const url = matchResult[1]
const name = matchResult[2]

console.log(`url: "${url}" name: "${name}"`)
```

Comment: Indeed this is the right answer, though I already figured it out few minutes ago.. but thanks for help